# How to stop this regex from being greedy?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have the following regex http://regexr.com/3d1qb and it is one those that is greedy now I understand why this is happening. But how can I fix this?

Currently it is matching the whole thing as one. But the way I want it is to be matched twice not once.

Comment: Sorry updated the link the example wasnt what i wanted.

Comment: Do you realize that the answer is *already* in your regex?

Comment: Question is what part you want to make lazy ?

Comment: *What I want is to match them all differently not all of them as one* could you add an **explicit** desired output ?

Comment: Updated the question sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A regexp is not the right tool for parsing html. This one works for the examples, but it will not work with a real html:

```
(<a href="https:\/\/www.example.com\/finance-glossary.*?">)([^<]*)(<\/a>)
```

For example, in your test, the first `<a.*?href` can match anything until a `href` is found, in any element, attribute or text. It's just not something you should do with a regex.

http://regexr.com/3d1qh

Comment: Hmm you are right I will take it in consideration, thank you.